# How would you limit a buffer size and also return the buffer limit in c++?

Tags: java, c++, buffer, limit, bytebuffer

I know that in Java you use Bytebuffer .limit() but I'm not sure how to do it in c++. Thanks! ☺

Here is part of the code:

```
float _proj[16];
float _projb[1];

//this->_proj.flip().limit(16);
swap(_proj, _projb);
this->_proj.get(this->proj);
```

I used std::swap method instead of flip since there ins't ByteBuffer in c++.

Comment: C++ doesn't have a "bytebuffer" as such. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466756/c-equivalent-of-java-bytebuffer) has some suggested alternatives.

Comment: It depends what you are using as your buffer. Please give us more context to what you are doing.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466756/c-equivalent-of-java-bytebuffer

Comment: @Galik Hope the change helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some close alternatives are `std::vector` and `std::array`.

If you want to use an array of bytes, usually `uint8_t`, you will need to pass the array to functions, *as well as the capacity and the number of elements in the array*.

The issue is that when arrays are passed to functions, the array decays down to a pointer to the first element, without any capacity information.

There are no facilities to prevent you from indexing beyond the limits (capacity) of the array.  This is why `std::vector` is a safer choice.